# react-redux Provider gives error “onlyChild must be passed a children with exactly one child” in IE 10/11

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, reactjs, redux, react-redux

This component works exactly as expected in Chrome, Safari, Firefox, and MS Edge:

```
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import Store from './Store';
import Root from './Root';

class AppProvider extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Provider store={Store}>
        <Root />
     </Provider>
     );
  }
}

export default AppProvider;
```

But on IE 10/11, it throws:
"Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop `children` supplied to `Provider`, expected a single ReactElement."

But Root is a single ReactElement? Here's the Root element below:

```
import Main from './Main';
import ProjectList from './ProjectList';
import ContactList from './ContactList';

import { Router, Route, IndexRoute } from 'react-router';
import { History } from './History';

class Root extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Router history={History}>
        <Route path="/" component={Main}>
          <IndexRoute component={ProjectList}></IndexRoute>
          <Route path="/:projectId" component={ContactList}></Route>
        </Route>
      </Router>
    );
  }
}

export default Root;
```

I actually only created Root because of this issue; previously, I just put the router right into the provider, without any argument from other browsers.

Comment: Maybe check the React Dev Tools in chrome to see if something fishy is going on

Comment: Also the constructor in your Root component isn't doing anything, you can just omit it.

Comment: You're right, I added it almost superstitiously to see if it could have anything to do with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was a result of error on my own part. I was somehow using two different versions of React.